# Get vanityName with thephpleague/oauth2-linkedin

Tags: php, symfony, linkedin-api, symfony4

I'm trying to get vanityName so I can concatenate with LinkedIn's URL to make the public profile URL, but I can only get some other fields, like lastname, email, id, etc.

I'm setting `'scope' => 'r_basicprofile'`, but I'm not sure if I'm putting it in the right place.

Already tried to set `'scope' => 'r_basicprofile'` inside `$provider = new LinkedIn([...])` and inside $options:

```
$options = [
    'state' => 'OPTIONAL_CUSTOM_CONFIGURED_STATE',
    'scope' => ['r_liteprofile','r_emailaddress']
];

$authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
public function setLinkedin(Request $request)
    {
        $provider = new LinkedIn([
            'clientId' => 'clientIdHere',
            'clientSecret' => 'clientSecretHere',
            'redirectUri' => 'http://' . $request->getHost() . ':' . $request->getPort() . $this->generateUrl('vincular_linkedin'),
            'scope' => 'r_basicprofile'
        ]);

        if (!$request->get('code')) {

            $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
            $this->get('session')->set('oauth2state', $provider->getState());
            header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
            exit;
        } elseif (!$request->get('state') || ($request->get('state') !== $this->get('session')->get('oauth2state'))) {

            $this->get('session')->remove('oauth2state');
            exit('Invalid state');
        } else {
            $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                'code' => $request->get('code')
            ]);


            try {
                $user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);

                echo '<pre>';
                var_dump($user);
                echo '</pre>';
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                exit ($e);
            }

        }
        return new Response();
    }
```

I'm following [this](https://packagist.org/packages/league/oauth2-linkedin) and [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile).

Using Symfony 4.3.3 with PHP 7+.

My app is already registered, but I only have three permissions: r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile and w_member_social. I can't change it.

Installed LinkedIn API via composer.